# How can I extract key words from a list and create individual column for each one of them?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, list, numpy, jupyter-notebook

For example, I have a list like ['Hot Pot', 'Korean BBQ', 'BBQ', 'Korean'] or ['Desserts', 'Modern Australian'] under cuisine column
How can I extract each element from the list and creat separate column for unique cuisine query?

Comment: Your question is unclear/ambiguous, please provide a `DataFrame` constructor for a minimal example and the matching expected output. Clear examples are worth a thousand words.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

unique_cols = df['cuisine'].unique()
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=unique_cols)
```